# Is there a command-line shell for JSP? Just like the php cli program

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

PHP can be executed as a script, without the existence of a web server. e.g `php script.php`

I'm wondering if there's anything similar for JSP?

Comment: JSP? Not trivially, although you could just use curl/wget and a simple server. But... why would you want to? JSP is only the view layer and shouldn't have significant useful logic in it anyway.

Comment: But you can't execute the same PHP that way (i.e. one that uses request parameters, etc.), can you? It has to be written differently.

Answer (score 0):

One can't really invoke a servlet without a request and context, per se. The closest I would imagine is `javac` to compile and `java` to run (main methods), though it's somewhat more of a difference than php-cli to php on web.

Comment: I found jspc but not sure where to download it

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible out of box. But you could implement it. Jsp is in fact compiled servlet that has public methods. So you can implement your own CLI "container" that can run jsp. It would just dump the result (html) code of jsp.

To do it:

1. compile jsp into servlet
2. create your implementation of `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` (and several other related objects as well)
3. run servlets service method with your classes
4. dump output to `System.out` stream

I doubt that it will be usefull enough to put energy in.

Comment: @warl0ck - do you have any question?